# Zoom extent issue in d3 axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am using **d3 axis** to show the bar graph and i have added **zoom interaction** to it.
I am adding zoom interaction like this,

```
d3.zoom(xScale).on("zoom", jQuery.proxy(function(){
       //Do somthing on zooming.                
       },this));
},this));
```

On Zooming the axis i have to get the at what level the axis is zoomed, 
suppose consider i have time axis on zooming it will show the labels in day level, after zooming again it will show the axis in hour level. So how to get whether it is zoomed in day level or hour level after zooming?

Comment: this reference link could be useful to fit your requirement http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/9689303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are targeting `d3` version 4, the best way to handle this is with the zoom functionality's [rescaleX](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#transform_rescaleX).  Say we have the following zoom handler where `x` is the scale tied to the x-axis:

```
function zoomed() {
  var newScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x));
  console.log(newScale.domain());
}
```

Would log the bounds (min/max) of your zoomed axis.